# visual basic procedure too large error & ambiguous name detected worksheet_change

Tags: vba

I have a large VBA macro which consists of one large Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range).

It first gives me the procedure too large error as it is really big.

When I tried to break it into 3 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range).

this error shows up:

> ambiguous name detected worksheet_change

any clues I can work around these 2 errors?

thanks in advance

here are my codes, the actual codes have tonnes of conditions and text check for each target address

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
If Target.Address = [rng_opt1].Address Then 
If [rng_opt1] = "x" Then 
If [rng1_1] = "z" then 
[rng1_1] = " " 
End if 
End If 
End if
End sub
```

thanks to @urdearboy, I got it solved, my final codes is like this (much simplified version). it's tricky and took me a while as my target has defined name

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = [rng_opt1].Address Then
      Call Opt1(Target)
    ElseIf Target.Address = [rng1_1].Address Then
      Call Opt11(Target)
    End if

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue

End Sub

Sub Opt1(Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = [rng_opt1].Address Then
           If [rng_opt1] = "x" Or [rng_opt1] = "y" Then
              If [rng1_1] = "z" 
                   [rng1_1] = " "
              End If
           End if
    End if
End Sub

Sub Opt11(Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = [rng1_1].Address Then
      If [rng1_1] = " " Then
        If [rng1_2] = " " And [rng1_3] = " " And [rng1_4] = " " Then
           [rng1_1] = "y"
           [rng1_2] = "x"
        End If
      End If
    End if 
 End sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous name detected Worksheet\_Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528166/ambiguous-name-detected-worksheet-change)

Comment: Welcome! Please look at the possible duplicate question, and see if that answers your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one `WorkSheet_Change` event on a worksheet which is why you are getting the **Ambiguous Name Detected** error.

If your code is too long, try to create your actions in a `Sub` and then call those subs given certain criteria. This way, you can limit your `WorkSheet_Change` code to *strictly* evaluate the `Target`.

In you `WorkSheet_Change` code you can have something like:

```
If Target.Value = “x” Then
  Call SubX
ElseIF Target.Value = “y” Then
  Call SubY
ElseIF Target.Value = “z” Then
  Call SubZ
End IF
```

---

```
SubX ()
   ‘Do Something
End Sub
```

---

```
SubY ()
   ‘Do Something
End Sub
```

---

```
SubZ ()
   ‘Do Something
End Sub
```

---

### Note:

You will need to disable events before you make any physical change to your sheet otherwise you will find yourself in a infinite loop and crash your instance of excel. Use the below method to avoid this issue:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
   ‘Physical changes to worksheet
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Yes, I know you dont have to use the `Call` line. It just makes it clear what’s happening and gives context, and sometimes that is more important than shortening the character limit of a macro. (Preemptively getting out ahead of the comment I get 9/10 for using `Call`)

Comment: thank you so very much, I was trying to break it as some suggested to tackle the "procedure too large" error, but couldn;t tackle how the pass the target value for the worksheet change event. I am going to try your suggestion tomorrow. thanks so much!

Comment: You can also pass parameters into the subs, but that is off-topic as far as how to do that in this question. If you need to pass some variable into your sub (maybe the target address?) you can google that. Pretty straight forward, or you can come back here for help